# Reading file on ramfs is slow

Tags: java, linux, ram

I have copied some files in ramfs and local Linux filesystem also and try to read those files using my java program give below

```
 public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    int length = args.length;
    long s = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for(int i=0; i<length; ++i){
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[i]));
        String line = "";
        while((line=br.readLine())!=null){

        }
        br.close();
    }
    System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis()-s);
}
```

}

But in some cases ramfs is seems to be less efficient then Linux fs
File Size,No of files,Time in Ram Fs,Time in Reading Linux fs(in ms)

~500MB,1,2619,2837

~500MB,3,7018,7135

~2-3KB,17,3071,3024

Why there is increase in reading time in third case.
in case of ramfs files would be read from ram so ideally it should take less time.

any idea???

Comment: How did you create your ramfs? How are you running your program?

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with Java but more with Linux kernel.

Comment: Used below commands mkdir -p /mnt/ram

mount -t ramfs -o size=20m ramfs /mnt/ram and command used to run java program java -jar FileReader.jar <file list>